# Using Execute/CanExecute

Tags: c#, wpf

Could someone possibly give me an explanation of how to use the CanExecute and Execute Methods on RoutedCommands as I am currently trying to Execute one Command through another programmatically.

Comment: Basically CanExecute is for Binding it's value to some Button's Enabled property and Execute for the Command or click event

Comment: "*trying* to execute..." - you can just call execute on the ICommand object. What is the actual problem you are having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay lets say you have a button on your UI. And you want that button to fire up a command, lets say that command must update a rown in a database. But what happends ifthat explicit row is still used by another process. This way the CanExecute methods checks to see that the command can be made and if it can`t it disables the button and you cant click it until the command is available for execution. When you fire up the command, the Execute method of the ICommand object is processed.

Comment: Like this...

                if (savebutton.Command.CanExecute(sender))
                {
                    savebutton.Command.Execute(RefreshCommand);
                }
            }
right?

Comment: mmh kinda. but the button.Enable property is used most of the times. But thats right.

Comment: The whole idea of commands is that you can use them via binding. That way, a button will be automatically disabled when the CanExecute function returns false.